# how to split a shaple(like ellipse) and color the parts in drawio?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

In the below picture,i describe what want, since i do not know how to plot it at draw.io.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, generally it is not possible to split shapes that way.

Comment: The only possibility would be to use "pie chart" shape and change colors and part sizes under Property/Value on the right (when the shape is selected) Pie chart shape can be found under More shapes bottom left > Mockup graphics

Comment: same solution given by supports team, so sad. So is there any apps can do such thing?

Answer (score 0):

I use Inkscape for most custom shapes. I found [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oG2eqeZp9KU) on how to create your shape in Inkscape. Then you can just save it and add it to your diagram.

I haven't done anything like that, but here is an example of merging multiple shapes with a svg I made in Inkscape. I highlighted a transparent shape containing text to illustrate that all text is made in draw.io. I made the green shape a container and dragged the rest into it so that folding works normally.

[image: Example image made in Inkscape]

I guess you've already found a solution but if not, I hope this helped a bit!